# PyInstaller .exe breakdown after running

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to write an app which do calculations with user inputs. I use Tkinter, matplotlib and numpy. I executed the .py file with `pyinstaller`. Code works on spyder but when I pressed the run button in exe format it cannot give an output and shuts down.

Here is warnings of py to exe process:

```
2393 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.

80765 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
80935 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!

95455 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll

95582 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll

96194 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll

96246 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll

96531 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll

96535 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll

96540 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll

96639 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll

96868 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\users\hp\anaconda3\envs\python\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Include the used `pyinstaller` line of code too.

Comment: I used in cmd: pyinstaller ASRS.py --onefile --windowed

Comment: Change the code to `pyinstaller --onefile -c ASRS.py` and run the exe and copy the error that comes up in the terminal.

Comment: pyinstaller returns same warnings. When I run the exe in cmd it is again shutting down and does not return any errors

Comment: These arent any errors, there are jus warnings. But there is something else going on with your exe

Comment: Could it be related to the modules used ?

Comment: Possibly `matplotlib`, I have used `numpy` without any issue in the past

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will deal with modules.